# Azure ARM getting Values from variable

Tags: azure, arm, azure-resource-manager

i have to create an ARM template an currently im stucked in using the variables with extendend values.

I define the variables

```
"variables": {
    "NetWorkID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
}
```

And now i want to get the first subnet of the virtual Network.
I don´t know how to get the value.

i tested this but this doesn´t work:

```
"subnet": {
    "id": "[variables('NetWorkID().subnet.ID')]"
}
```

Can i get a hint how to work with these variables?

Answer (score 1):

usually you refer to subnets using the syntax bellow.

What you can do is pass the virtualNetworkName and subnet1Name as parameters and use the resourceid() expression.

```
"subnet": {
  "id": "[resourceId(parameters('virtualNetworkResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnet1Name'))]"
}
```

Another way to do this, if you refer to the same subnet accross the arm template, is to build this resourceid in the variables instead of the resources and then use the variable in the resources properties.

Example:

```
    "variables": {
      "subnetId": "[resourceId(parameters('virtualNetworkResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnet1Name'))]"
    },
"resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",
            "apiVersion": "xxxx",
            "name": "xxxxx",
            "location": "xxxxx",
            "properties": {
                "privateLinkServiceConnections": [
                    {
                        "name": "xxxxx",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateLinkServiceId": "xxxxx",
                            "groupIds": [
                                "blob"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                **"subnet": {
                    "id": "[variables('subnetId')]"
                }**,
                "customDnsConfigs": [
                    {
                        "fqdn": "xxxxxx"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
]
```

You can also try to list the existing subnets using the reference() function

```
"subnetId":"[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', variables('vnetName')), '2022-01-01', 'Full').properties.subnets]"
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your ideas.
On that way it´s working, but i don´t want to provide the subnetname. I want to use the ARM to provide new resources to exiting Resource Groups and virtual Networks. But in the past, there were different SubnetNames. So the plan was, to get the first Subnet of the virtual Network and using this to deploy the resource

Comment: I think you can use the reference() function to list the existing subnets. Can you test? I'm not sure it works because I haven't tested it.

Comment: note that using ```reference()``` to get the subnets is not deterministic - you may get different results over time.  Using the name (not the ordinal position) is a little more robust.

Comment: where you able to get it working @StefanSchulze?